# Yii for mobile browser

Tags: mobile, yii, responsive-design

I intend to rebuild my existing web site using the Yii framework.  I want it to be mobile-friendly, so I've decided to start right off with a generic small-screen size (mobile safari, perhaps?)

I thought I would find a ready-to-go option in Yii, ideally something like *Uncomment this line in the layout page for small-size display*.  Not there, nothing concrete in the documentation, and nothing at the [blueprint css site](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).

I hit Google for `mobile yii`, `'responsive web' yii` and so on, thinking *Okay, I might have to patch in someone's css solution -- not a great way to start my Yii learning, but maybe doable.*  All I found were tips and approaches, and they tended to assume I had experience building for mobile browsers.

(Which I don't.  So far the most important thing I've learned during this search is that CSS alone doesn't make it happen; apparently **jquery mobile** is the tool of choice.  I mention this only so you'll know the state of my understanding.)

I'm all for "wet paint technology" and not having everything handed to me, but I imagined Yii would have a response for the mobile-app challenge.  What am I missing?  (Maybe some choice keywords, since my research produces so little?)  How do you suggest I move forward?

Comment: Yii is web development framework, your website is mobile firendly or not will depends on your design and layout and many design related things, it got nothing to do with the framework as far as i am concern, no matter which framework you use, still it will be the case, but you can make you website mobile friendly using other framework like jquery mobile, which you can intergrate into the Yii or even Zend without a problem, framework handles the the application architecture not the front end presentation logic or the design...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework. Create a new theme in yii and put all the boostrap files in that theme .. your yii application will start working in responsive design mode. You can also use the [bootstrap extension for yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/)